# Fish swim in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, python-imaging-library, gif

I want to use the python pygame module to make a 2D "fishtank".

Basically I will load a jpg image as background and load a gif animated image depicting fish swimming and make it move.

I know how to make an static image move but how to make a gif image move while the image itself is animated.

I have PIL installed, do sure if need to use it.

If that does not work, I can also break apart the gif file into several static frames and cyclically make each of them show on screen. When the latter one is posted, the former one needs to be removed, how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I used in my name to get PyGame animation to work:

```
class Animation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, fps = 6):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Slice source image to array of images
        self.images = self.loadSliced(img)

        # Track the time we started, and the time between updates.
        # Then we can figure out when we have to switch the image.
        self._start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self._delay = 1000 / fps
        self._last_update = 0
        self._frame = 0
        self.image = self._images[self._frame]

def loadSliced(w, h, filename):
    """
    Pre-conditions:
        Master can be any height
        Sprites frames must be the same width
        Master width must be len(frames)*frames.width

    Arguments: 
        w -- Width of a frame in pixels
        h -- Height of a frame in pixels
        filename -- Master image for animation
    """
    images = []

    if fileExists( img, "Animation Master Image"):
        master_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        master_width, master_height = master_image.get_size()
        for i in range(int(master_width/w)):
            images.append(master_image.subsurface((i*w, 0, w, h)))
    return images

def update(self, t):
    # Note that this doesn't work if it's been more than self._delay
    # time between calls to update(); we only update the image once
    # then. but it really should be updated twice

    if t - self._last_update > self._delay:
        self._frame += 1
        if self._frame >= len(self._images): 
            self._frame = 0
            self.image = self._images[self._frame]
            self._last_update = t
        self.image = self._images[self._frame]
        self._last_update = t

def getFrame(self, screen):
    # Update Frame and Display Sprite
    self.update(pygame.time.get_ticks())
    return self.image
```

Comment: Looks good - could you add something that explains how what you're doing helps the OP?

Comment: @GHC: He's creating a **spritesheet** from a single image. Then uses a timer to switch `image`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use this class ?  I am pretty new to pygame, many sorry.